# How to access properties of function within function

Tags: javascript

How do I access `isExpanded`, `collapsedHeight` and `expandedHeight` inside the jQuery click handler for `element`.
**The way it's written now won't work because `this` means something else inside the click handler than it does outside of it.**

```
function CoolSelect(element)
{
    this.element=element;
    this.isExpanded=false;
    this.collapsedHeight=$(element).height();
    this.expandedHeight=this.collapsedHeight+$('ul',element).height();

    $(this.element).click(function()
    {
        var newHeight;
        if(this.isExpanded){newHeight=this.collapsedHeight;}
        else{newHeight=this.expandedHeight;}
        $(this.element).animate({height:newHeight},100,'liniar');
    });
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the value of `this` to another variable in the outer function.

```
var that = this;
```

Then use `that` in the inner function.

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't it be easier if I just declared each class property as a `var` and just access it in the inside functions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to save a reference to this.
This code uses `var that = this;`

```
function CoolSelect(element)
{
    this.element=element;
    this.isExpanded=false;
    this.collapsedHeight=$(element).height();
    this.expandedHeight=this.collapsedHeight+$('ul',element).height();
    var that = this;

    $(this.element).click(function()
    {
        var newHeight;
        if(that.isExpanded){newHeight=that.collapsedHeight;}
        else{newHeight=that.expandedHeight;}
        $(that.element).animate({height:newHeight},100,'liniar');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Lime. I chose the answer that was posted first. Otherwise, yours was just as good.

Comment: 16 seconds make all the difference :D

Comment: I had no other criteria. Haha.